# Changing the Button variant of KeyboardDatePicker of Material UI

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

i have created a website with Material UI in which all buttons are of the variant "outlined". Except in the Calendar of the KeyboardDatePicker. In this Dialog the "ok" and the "cancel" Button are in the standard look.

I didn't find any prop in the api (https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/KeyboardDatePicker) to change the variant of the button.

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the only way (I found) to apply a custom style to KeyboardDatePicker buttons is to override the style of `MuiButton` in `ThemeProvider`.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/customicon-forked-6l8ff?file=/src/App.js) a working example.

Basically you have to:

1. Wrap `KeyboardDatePicker` in `ThemeProvider` like:

   ```
   <ThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}>
     <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
      <DatePicker />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
   </ThemeProvider>
   ```
2. create a `muiTheme` using `createMuiTheme` in this way:

   ```
   const muiTheme = createMuiTheme({
     overrides: {
       MuiButton: {
         textPrimary: {
           border: "1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23)",
           padding: "5px 15px"
         }
       }
      }
    });
   ```

Thats it. The result is:

[image]

Note: in this way you are overriding all the `MuiButton`s you are using in your application (but for you should not be a problem since you said that you are using button outlined everywhere).

Answer (score 0):

Riffing off @Giovanni Esposito's idea, you can use a theme to edit or remove styles from the primary Buttons, and nest your own buttons using okLabel and cancelLabel which accept custom components:

```
import {
  Button,
  createTheme,
  ThemeProvider,
} from "@material-ui/core";

import {
  KeyboardDatePicker,
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider,
} from "@material-ui/pickers";

import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns";

const MuiPickersTheme = createTheme({
  ...appThemeOptions,
  overrides: {
    ...(appThemeOptions.overrides || {}),
    MuiButton: {
      textPrimary: {
        padding: "0",
      },
    },
  },
});

const CustomDatePicker = (props) => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={MuiPickersTheme}>
      <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
        <KeyboardDatePicker
          {...props}

          cancelLabel={
            <Button color="default" disableElevation>
              Cancel
            </Button>
          }

          okLabel={
            <Button color="secondary" variant="contained" disableElevation>
              Apply
            </Button>
          }
        />
      </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default CustomDatePicker;
```

Note that this may not be the best performance wise; see https://v4.mui.com/customization/theming/#a-note-on-performance